# How do I insert multiple values into PG with different where clauses?

Tags: postgresql, pg

Here is how my data is set up:

```
Zone
------
zone_id
value
other_id
```

I am going to have the same `zone_id` for all of the updates.  I am only updating the `value`, but where the `other_id` is different in each case.

ie:  `zone_id: 1, [{value: 10, other_id: 12}, {value: 40, other_id: 17}, ...]`

I want to do this all in one statement.

`UPDATE zone set value = {value} where zone_id = {id} and other_id = {other}`, but I want to set multiple `value`s in the same statement.

How do I do this?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear, but I think you are asking to set the `value` conditionally. So something like this should work:

```
UPDATE zone
SET value = CASE other_id
              WHEN 12 THEN 10
              WHEN 17 THEN 40
              -- and so on
              ELSE value
            END
WHERE zone_id = 1
```